# Multiple date range stock overbooked query

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling a bit with a query and I'm not sure if its possible in pure sql or needs to be backed by php.

Basically I want to generate an order report listing the products that have been overbooked in the system.

Table structure:

orders

```
id int
bookingStart DATETIME
bookingEnd DATETIME
```

order_lines

```
id int
qty int
product_id int
booking_id int
```

products

```
id int
stock int
```

An order can contain multiple lines with the same product. So there needs to be a SUM for each product on an order. Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to accomplish this?

I have tried looping in a specific time interval with a subquery, but it does not take into account the overlap between different bookings and im kinda stuck here, if it can be done with a single query:

```
SELECT  (SELECT SUM(lin2.qty) FROM booking_lines lin2,orders b2
                       WHERE
                         lin2.product_id=e.id    AND
                       b2.id=lin2.booking_id  AND                           (
                       (b2.bookingStart BETWEEN b1.bookingStart AND b1.bookingEnd) OR
                       (b2.bookingEnd BETWEEN b1.bookingStart AND b1.bookingEnd) OR
                       (b2.bookingStart < b1.bookingStart AND b2.bookingEnd >     b1.bookingEnd)                           
                       )    as booked SUM(lin1.qty) 
                 FROM orders b1
                 LEFT JOIN order_lines lin1 ON b1.id=lin1.booking_id
                 LEFT JOIN products e ON e.id=lin1.product_id

                (
                    (b1.bookingStart BETWEEN '$s' AND '$e') OR
                    (b1.bookingEnd BETWEEN '$s' AND '$e') OR
                    (b1.bookingStart < '$s' AND b1.bookingEnd > '$e') 
        )
         GROUP BY b1.id,lin1.product_id
```

The problem
If we have product x with a stock of 10.

Order 1 has booked 3 product x
Order 2 has booked 5 product x
Order 3 has booked 8 product x

The lines below indicate the booked timespan

__*_*___*Order 1 x:3****_*__*_***
       ***_*__***Order 2 x:5****_*__*_*_**
***_*__*_*__*_*___***Order 3 x:8****_*__*_*__**
                                            **__***order 4 x:2***_**

So its only when the 3 orders overlap that product x is actually overbooked, what i cant figure out is how to create a query capable of detecting that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post sample data, desired output based on it, and what you've tried so far so we can see your effort.

Comment: In your query you have a `LEFT JOIN` to a table called `booking_lines`. Did you mean `order_lines` or it's a totally different table?

Comment: Based on your comment to my answer below, I think you need to specify the granularity of the time-frame in order to figure out what the overlap is.  Days?, Hours?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an instance of MySql to test with, but have you tried something like this:

```
select p.id, p.stock, t.bookedQty
from products as p
    inner join (
            select ol.product_id, sum(ol.qty) as bookedQty
            from order_lines as ol
                inner join orders as o on ol.booking_id = o.id
            where o.bookingStart between '2013-06-10' and '2013-06-11'
                    and t.bookedQty > p.stock
            group by ol.product_id) as t
```

--*See comment 1*--

I used the SqlFiddle schema from tftd's answer below (thanks).  This should generate every day for the next 100 that has an overbooking, the quantity booked, and the quantity in stock:

```
SELECT
        date,
        p.product_id,
        sum(ol.qty) AS total_booked,
        p.stock AS available
FROM  (
        SELECT c.date
        FROM
          (SELECT curdate() + interval (a.a + (10 * b.a)) DAY AS date
           FROM
             (SELECT 0 AS a
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
           JOIN
             (SELECT 0 AS a
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
          ) AS c
        WHERE c.date >= curdate() AND c.date < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 100 DAY)
    ) AS gendates
    INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.bookingStart <= gendates.date AND o.bookingEnd > gendates.date
    INNER JOIN order_lines AS ol ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
    INNER JOIN products AS p ON ol.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY gendates.date, p.product_id, p.stock
HAVING total_booked > p.stock
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5061e/25

[Date generation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

Comment: I tried something along those lines but it dosent take overlaps into account. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: It is very close to what i want except that bookingStart and bookingEnd is a DATE TIME so i need to find the specific interval where the overbooking occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(255),
    stock      INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id     INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    bookingStart DATETIME,
    bookingEnd   DATETIME
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE order_lines (
    line_id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_id      INT,
    product_id    INT,
    qty           INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(order_id)   REFERENCES orders(order_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO products(name, stock) VALUES('Product 1', 8);
INSERT INTO products(name, stock) VALUES('Product 2', 14);
INSERT INTO products(name, stock) VALUES('Product 3', 25);

INSERT INTO orders(bookingStart,bookingEnd) VALUES(NOW(), (NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR));
INSERT INTO orders(bookingStart,bookingEnd) VALUES(NOW(), (NOW() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR));
INSERT INTO orders(bookingStart,bookingEnd) VALUES(NOW(), (NOW() + INTERVAL 4 HOUR));

INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(1, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(1, 1, 8);
INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(2, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(2, 2, 10);
INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(3, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(3, 3, 8);
INSERT INTO order_lines(order_id, product_id, qty) VALUES(3, 3, 10);
```

To get the overbooked products:

```
SELECT
  products.*,
  SUM(order_lines.qty) as sum_qty
FROM products
LEFT JOIN order_lines ON order_lines.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = order_lines.order_id
WHERE orders.bookingStart >= '2013-06-12' 
AND orders.bookingEnd <= '2013-06-14'
GROUP BY order_lines.order_id, order_lines.product_id
HAVING sum_qty > products.stock
```

Will return `Product 1` and `Product 2`, because the sum of `qty` in `order_lines` is bigger than `products.stock` (which is probably the available quantity of the product?).

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31f9b/1)

Comment: Yeah but it needs to take the time interval into account because its a rental product. So its only if its overbooked in a specific time interval, the problem is there can be multiple orders spanning the same time interval so it needs to find the maximum qty, taking the time interval into account.

Comment: Well just add a `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY` in the query and it will filter them. I did not add it because I had just 3 records.

Comment: @sdbb as I said in my previous comment, just add a `WHERE` clause to the query. You can try it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117773/4 to see the result. This is what you want, right?

Comment: Except i want to execute the query and then it should be able to find the maximum qty booked at any given time where it is greater than the stock, not on a single order. For instance according to the example in the question order 1,2,3 overlap giving a total qty of 16, order 3,4 overlap giving a total qty 10

Comment: So, you want to get all orders between `DATE1` and `DATE2` which hold products over the limit (`product.stock`), is that right ?

Comment: I want to find the combined totals not just on a single order e.g. as above. If two or more orders combined have booked more than stock in any given time interval.